# Where can I find a professional image gallery built on a javascript framework?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image-gallery

I'm looking to find a galleria replacement, hopefully using jQuery but other javascript frameworks such as prototype or mootools are fine too.

I used galleria a while back, and I need a similar product now. Unfortunately, the devkick.com domain seems to have disappeared in the meantime and I'm wary of using products that aren't actively maintained.

I'm willing to pay up to $50 per site for licensing costs, if the product meets my needs.

I'm specifically looking for a gallery with the following features:

- Every image in the gallery preloads asap, not as the user clicks "next"
- Minimalist default css to keep my subsequent styling headaches down, preferably a "darkroom" style by default, much as galleria looks
- Each element that constructs the image gallery should be simple and logical to reference with CSS
- As easy to install as adding a css class to a single unordered list
- No dependencies other than the core jQuery/other library, including "easing" and other effects must be optional
- Works on browsers back to IE6, Firefox 3, Safari (and iPhone), Chrome, Opera
- Has a javascript API that lets me trigger callback functions on common events such as "user clicks next" or "image loads"
- degrades gracefully without javascript, either displays images as a list, or just displays the first image in the list
- bonus: The gallery can display other content, such as video or external sites, like the modal boxes at shadowbox-js.com
- well documented
- minimal bandwidth requirement - .js file should be ~10kb minified
- **bonus:** The gallery source is hosted on a reliable CDN like google's
- **bonus:** Thumbnails for images do not appear until the main image has loaded
- **bonus:** includes ability to set parameters with JSON to change common behaviours, such as slide/fade transitions or automatic image switch every X seconds

Comment: you need a CDN for a 10kb file?

Comment: I'm in australia, latency to the US is often 900ms. Since I can't control where my client's host their files, yes I'd like a CDN for a 10kb file.

Comment: Whys this getting upvotes? It's got nothing to do with programming he just wants a script.

Comment: I guess it's getting upvotes because it's "detailed and specific, written clearly and simply, of interest to other programmers". That's the requirements for a question, copied straight from the FAQ. If you don't understand, please redirect your question to http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: SO is full of morons who know a lot. Using styling in your posts will get you upvotes almost regardless of it's content. You're requesting a complete script and are not willing to write it your self which is not what this site is for.

Comment: depends on your point of view. I don't distinguish between asking for advice here, blatantly getting a portion of code rewritten by a professional in the process, and basing a portion of work off a mature script developed elsewhere. Both are simply pragmatic ways to get the job done, and learn something in the process. Please drop the elitist undertones, I notice nobody has actually had a crack at actually addressing the question, just being arrogant and narrow minded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Galleriffic appears to be the best bet.

http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/